# How to enable direct payment in Moneybookers

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, credit-card

I want to enable direct payment for the customers using credit/debit card in Moneybookers payment gateway.

It’s asking the buyer to login/register to Moneybookers.

I tried the hidden variable payment_methods, but it failed.

How can I implement direct payment for the customers through credit/debit card?

Comment: What did Moneybookers say when you asked their support this question about their service?

Answer (score 2):

```
    <input type="hidden" name="hide_login" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

And you must be a Merchant (you must have a Merchant account).